# html video showing black screen on Crome

Tags: html, video, autoplay

It's working fine on all browsers but showing a black screen while loading in Crome. Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: <video class="i_video" id="i_video" autoplay muted loop playsinline
                            src="videos/intro.mp4"></video>

Comment: If you can share a link to the video or a similar video which does not work, it will make it easier for people to help you